# On exponent mod $2p$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Assume $p$ is a prime.

Assume $g$ is primitive root for both $\Bbb Z_p$ and $\Bbb Z_{2p}$.

We know in discrete logarithm problem $z$ is unique $\bmod(p-1)$ in $g^z=h\bmod p$.

Is it true that $z'$ is unique $\bmod(2p-1)$ in $g^{z'}=h\bmod 2p$? Or is it just unique mod $\bmod(p-1)$?

Answer (score 1):

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we have an isomorphism of rings $\mathbb Z_{2p} \cong \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_p$. This restricts to an isomorphism of the (multiplicative) group of units: $\mathbb Z_{2p}^* \cong \mathbb Z_2^* \times \mathbb Z_p^*$. Now, $\mathbb Z_2^*$ is the trivial group, while $\mathbb Z_p^*$ is cyclic with order $p-1$, so we conclude $\mathbb Z_{2p}^*$ is cyclic with order $p-1$. Therefore, if $g$ is a generator of $\mathbb Z_{2p}^*$ (i.e., a primitive root), then $g$ has order $p-1$, so $g^z=g^{z'}$ if and only if $z\equiv z' \pmod{p-1}$.

Comment: Yes, under addition it is. Is there a problem?

Comment: So for $\Bbb Z_{pqr}$ exponent is unique mod $(p-1)(q-1)(r-1)$ ?

Comment: Well, if $p,q,r$ are distinct primes, then $\mathbb Z_{pqr}^*$ is not a cyclic group, so there is no generator (primitive root). But the order of the group is $(p-1)(q-1)(r-1)$, so by Lagrange's theorem the order of any element will divide $(p-1)(q-1)(r-1)$. This means that for any given element $g$, it will be true that if $z\equiv z' \mod (p-1)(q-1)(r-1)$ then $g^z = g^{z'}$, but the converse will not be true. Rather, we will have $g^z = g^{z'}$ if and only if $z\equiv z' \mod |g|$, where $|g|$ is the order of $g$.

Comment: sure but are there elements with order $\phi(pqr)$  always (for that matter any composite)?

Comment: No, if there were an element of order $\phi(pqr)=(p-1)(q-1)(r-1)$, then this would imply that $\mathbb Z_{pqr}^*$ is cyclic, which it is not. The largest possible order of an element would be the least common multiple of $p-1$, $q-1$, and $r-1$.

Comment: but such generators are possible for $\Bbb Z_{pq}$ right?

Comment: Only if one of $p$ or $q$ is 2. For if $p$ and $q$ are both odd primes, then $p-1$ and $q-1$ are both even, so their least common multiple is not equal to $(p-1)(q-1)$.